# Storing data with a switch statement in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I need help with how to store something inside a string and later show it through the menu. When I try to save a value to the switch statement it doesn't save it even if I put the string outside the switch statement. I need also know how to later on clean the string, so the program reset itself.
Here's what I have done so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ryggsäcken_NTI_Uppgift2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)    
        {
            bool isRunning = true;
            while(isRunning)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tVälkommen till ryggsäcken! vänligen välj ett av dessa val med en siffra.");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[0]För en kort Instruktion till hur detta program fungerar, välj siffra 0");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[1]För att spara föremål i ryggsäcken, välj siffra 1");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[2]För att visa vad som ligger i ryggsäcken, välj val 2 ");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[3]För att rensa ryggsäcken välj val 3 ");
                Console.WriteLine("\t[4]För att avsluta, välj siffra 4");
                Console.Write("\tVälj en siffra: ");
                int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                string item ="";

                //Använda menyvalet med if eller switch

                switch (menyVal)
                {
                    case 0:
                        { 
                            //Anvisningar till användaren
                            Console.WriteLine("Detta program hjälper dig att spara dina föremål som du vill lägga i ryggsäcken. För att spara ett föremål, vänligen välj val 1. För att öppna ryggsäcken och visa vad som är sparat välj val 2. För att rensa all data som sparats i ryggsäcken, välj då val 3. För att avsluta programmet, välj 4");
                            break;
                        }

                    case 1:
                        {

                            //Spara användarens föremål
                            Console.Write("skriv vad föremålet heter för att spara det i ryggsäcken: ");

                            item = Console.ReadLine();

                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {

                            //visa vad som ligger sparat i ryggsäcken
                            Console.WriteLine("Detta ligger just nu i ryggsäcken(visas inget är den tom): ");

                            Console.Write(item);

                            break;
                        }
                    case 3:
                        {
                            //Rensa ryggsäcken
                            Console.WriteLine("Rensar ryggsäcken... Nu kan du börja om från början igen.");
                            break;
                        }

                    case 4:
                        {
                            //Avsluta programmet
                            Console.WriteLine("Ryggsäcken stängs, Progammet avslutas. Hoppas du är nöjd, Hejdå!");
                            isRunning = false;
                            break;
                        }

                    default:
                        {

                            // med uppmaningen att skriva 0 - 4

                            Console.WriteLine("Du måste välja en siffra mellan 0-4!");

                            break;
                        }
                }

            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you translate the comments and strings inside the program to english so that everyone would know what's going on? And fix the spacing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `string item` initialisation line outside the `while(running)` loop:

```
bool isRunning = true;
string item = "";
while(isRunning)
{
    ...
}
```

Otherwise every iteration through the loop redeclares and re-initialises the `item`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! How can I reset the loop with my case nr 3 ?

Comment: By 'reset the loop' I guess you mean reset the item to its original value as if the user hadn't entered a value in option 1? In which case just say `item = "";` before the `break` inside the `case 3:` block

Comment: Thanks! Everything works except saving multiple strings to the string variable. How can I save more than one string at a time to the string called item?

Comment: That's a completely different question really. A single `string` variable can only hold one string value at any one time. If you want to store multiple strings you'll have to use a collection, most likely a `List<string>`, which you can `list.Add(item)`s to and `list.Clear()` to remove all strings from.